# Can't find main class in plugin.yml

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft

```
[04:48:05 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\HelloWorld.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `me.spoonle.helloworld.Main'
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:66) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:329) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:291) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:152) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:505) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.spoonle.helloworld.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:64) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        ... 7 more
```

I keep getting this error while loading my plugin onto my test server.
(I did check the other posts and they didn't help me)

plugin.yml file:

```
name: HelloWorld
version: 1.0
author: Spoonle
main: me.spoonle.helloworld.Main

commands:
  hello:
    alias: [hi]
```

do I need to add something? Those are spaces and not tabs. I saw that using TAB can break the yml file so I used spaces instead.

Code:

```
package me.spoonle.helloworld.commands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import me.spoonle.helloworld.Main;

public class HelloCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    private Main plugin;

    public HelloCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("hello").setExecutor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("Only players may execute this command!");
            return true;
        }
        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (p.hasPermission("hello.use")) {
            p.sendMessage("Hello!");
            return true;
        } else {
            p.sendMessage("You do not have permissions to use this command!");
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

This is just what I want the plugin to do. I don't know if this helps but its here if you need it.

Why can't I load my plugin??

Edit: I fixed the invalid plugin.yml. Now it is saying it can't find the main class. As stated above in the plugin.yml code, its me.spoonle.helloworld.Main and thats where my main file is located. How do I fix that now??

Answer (score 0):

Is the plugin.yml file in the same folder as the Main file?
If so, you just have to write

`main: Main`

Answer (score 0):

1. Your main class must extend **JavaPlugin**
2. Your plugin.yml must state **"main: "** and then your main class.

There should be a class called `Main` in the package `me.spoonle.helloworld`. If so, your main class is in the correct location.

Also, it is not good practice to use `Main` as your main class. Use the name of your program instead.

#### Example

Main:

```
package me.spoonle.helloworld;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
  @Override
  public void onEnable() {
    // Initialise HelloCommand here and set the executor of "hello" command
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisable() {

  }
}
```

Plugin.yml:

```
name: HelloWorld
version: 1.0
author: Spoonle
main: me.spoonle.helloworld.Main
```